# Java swing application with simple help documentation based on eclipse (no RCP application)

Tags: java, eclipse, swing

I developed a Java Swing application using Eclipse. I would like to integrate the existing help documentation into my GUI. 
Basically I want to start my help window with a typical menu item as common for most programs. So nothing 
fancy at all.

I spent already a lot time to find which option would be best for my case and I'm kind of stuck. I thought integrating the help would be straight 
forward but meanwhile I think this is not the case.

*If anyone can point me in the right direction or show me a tutorial where I can get the idea how to accomplish it with eclipse help 
and a swing application I would be really happy. I find a lot of tutorial discussing RCP applications or writing an eclipse plugin.
Somehow I tried a lot for such an easy usecase.*

The following options are available as far as I can tell:

**1. Eclipse like help**
My favorite option would be to use an eclipse like help window but after playing around a bit I have the slight feeling
that this is only possible for eclipse RCP applications. Since my Swing GUI is not a RCP application I think that wont work 
for me.

Is it possible to integrate the Eclipse help with only my help content into my Swing application? Eclipse won't be installed
on the PCs where my application is used.

Most probably those PCs are not even connected to the internet, so using the Eclipse help in info center mode is also not 
an option.

Using the eclipse help in standalone mode requires to specify the eclipse installation directory when launching it. That's where I'm stuck.

**2. Java help or Oracle help Java**
Using these options is my next call also not my favorite one. I think both options are kind of outdated.

For Java help I would probably follow the Docbook approach. Even if I don't understand why this is so complicated at
all...

**3. Custom panel**
I'm almost close to design a customized panel to display my help content. Then I'm at least able to make sure that I like
the way it is designed.

In the beginning I thought this might be more time consuming, but after reading what effort is necessary to get a nice looking
help with Java help I think this option is not the worst choice.

Thanks Joe

Comment: You didn't link to anything, so I can't be sure what you're talking about with Java help or Oracle help.  While the GUI look and feel might be outdated, the Java help I used was based loosely on the Eclipse help.  XML control files and HTML pages.

Comment: Hi Gilbert, thanks for your reply.
Java Help:
[link](http://javahelp.java.net)

Oracle Help:
[link](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/help/utilsoft-ohw-422139.html)

Eclipse help:
[link](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Fguide%2Fua_help_setup_standalone.htm)

Comment: You're right that Eclipse help is just for Eclipse RCP and Eclipse plug-ins.  I've not used the Oracle help.  Creating your own help GUI should be a last resort.  It's more complicated than it appears at first glace, if you want to divide your help into searchable sections.

Comment: Tanks again. Unfortunately this is not what I wanted to hear ;-) but it's finally a clear statement for me. The motivation of using JavaHelp is a bit low since its so old... But maybe I will give a try. I still have the option of starting the system browser with my help files. I'm a bit disappointed that this topic is totally neglected in Java. Again thanks a lot :-)

Answer (score 0):

My solution for now is to create the complete help system with [HelpNDoc](http://www.helpndoc.com) and then simply generate the HTML documentation.

The HTML document I will open from my swing GUI.

I also tried the CHTML but to be honest I like the look (which can be nicely configured) int the browser more.

Windows Help looks also too outdated to me. But that's just my personal opinion.

Right now this is the right solution for me and my energy will go into the help itself.

Thanks to everyone.

Joe